What are good sources for examples of field extensions?
I need to understand field extensions and Galois theory. I have read about the theory. But I think to digest the subject, i need to see lots of (non)normal, (in)separable, (in)finite dimensional, (non)Galois field extensions and any possible combination of them. Is there a good  books,notes that contain plenty of such examples?

These kinds of examples (perhaps in the form of exercises) should be in any good Galois theory book. Here are some common examples of extensions $F/K$:

$K=\mathbb{Q}$, $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})\cong \mathbb{Q}[t]/(t^3-2)$: an algebraic separable, but not normal (hence not Galois) extension (the polynomial $f(w)=w^3-2$ has a root in $F$, but does not split completely over $F$);
$K=$ field of rational functions $\mathbb{F}_q(x)$ over a finite field, where $q$ is a prime power and $x$ is an indeterminate, and $F=K(x^{1/p})=K[t]/(t^p-x)$: an algebraic normal but inseparable (hence not Galois) extension (the polynomial $g(w)=w^p-x$ is irreducible over $K$, but factorises as $g(w) = (w-t)^p$ over $F$);
$K=\mathbb{Q}$, $F=\bigcup_{a\in \mathbb{Q}^\times}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a})$: an infinite algebraic separable (hence Galois) extension, the maximal elementary abelian $2$-extension of $\mathbb{Q}$; another important such example is $F=\bigcup_n \mathbb{Q}(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}})$, the extension obtained by adjoining all roots of unity to $\mathbb{Q}$, which is also the maximal abelian extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ (this is the Kronecker–Weber theorem). Note that if you know about direct limits, then it is much better to write such extensions as direct limits rather than as unions. To make sense of the union, you need to already have constructed some over-field in which the union is being taken, while the injective limit construction allows you to build up infinite extensions "from the bottom up", without knowing anything about complex numbers, say.
$K=\mathbb{Q}$, $F=\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ or $F=\mathbb{Q}(x)$, where $x$ is an indeterminate: transcendental extensions, hence not Galois. Notice that in the first of these two examples, the bottom field matters: $\mathbb{R}(\pi)/\mathbb{R}$ is just the trivial extension.

